# Django - AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via ManagerLog instances

Tags: python, django

Soy nuevo en python, actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación, la cual se encarga de generar varios reportes muy sencillos, sin embargo hay un reporte el cual no he podido resolver aun, he investigado pero aun no consigo la solución.

Básicamente lo que quiero realizar es la siguiente consulta SQL a través del ORM:

```
select log.* from   file_managerfiles as file, log_managerlog as log where log.fileLog_id = file.id and file.lastUpload = TRUE
```

los modelos son los siguientes:

```
class ManagerFiles(models.Model):
    filesUpload = models.FileField(upload_to='log', unique=True)
    processingStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lastUpload = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ManagerLog(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    serialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sessionID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    moduleName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    operationName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    operationSpecific = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    fileLog = models.ForeignKey(ManagerFiles)
```

Dentro del último modelo (ManagerLog) cree un método que retorna todos los registros del modelo ManagerLog donde ManagerFile.lastUpload sea igual a TRUE:

```
# Report Last Upload File
def report_last_upload(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.filter(ManagerFiles__lastUpload=True)
```

Sin embargo al llamar este método (report_last_upload) en mi vista, obtengo el siguiente error:

> raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" %
>   cls.**name**) AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via ManagerLog
>   instances

No entiendo cual es el problema, espero me puedan ayudar, y de antemano gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el campo que hace la relación con `ManagerFiles` se llama `fileLog` según como lo has definido en tu modelo. Por lo tanto, la manera correcta de filtrarlo debería ser:

```
def report_last_upload(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.filter(fileLog__lastUpload=True)
```

Tienes que usar el nombre del campo definido y no el nombre del modelo al cual estás referenciando.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cesar, funcionó sin problema lo sugerido. Ahora que lo veo tiene sentido el porque se debe realizar la consulta de esa manera.

Comment: @LeonardoAntonioGarciaOlmos, recuerda que la forma de agradecer una buena respuesta es dándola por aceptada o el +1. Saludos